# Duplicate function calls while instrumenting with Pintool

Tags: instrumentation, intel-pin

I am trying to count the number of calls to malloc using a Pintool. I am using Pin3.6/source/tools/ManualExamples/malloc_mt.cpp as a reference. All my instrumentation does is looks for malloc definition when an image is loaded and inserts a print before the call to malloc.
I am testing it with the below small program I wrote.

My problem is that the call to malloc seems to be happening twice according to the tool whereas I am calling it just once in my test program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    char *p;
    p = malloc(0xfff);
    free(p);
}
```

On instrumenting this prints:

thread 0 entered main called from main of img /home/---/workspace/hw4/tst_progs/test

thread 0 entered malloc(4095) called from __libc_malloc of img /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6

thread 0 entered malloc(4095) called from __libc_malloc of img /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6

thread 0 entered malloc(1024) called from __libc_malloc of img /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6

Any suggestions?

Comment: What happens when you run it on a program with no malloc calls?

Comment: In that case, there are no calls to my malloc functions, i.e  the lines with malloc with sizes 4095 are not printed.

Comment: You should include the pintool code itself as well.